# Node-RED postgres node error connection timeout

Tags: postgresql, node-red

After updating Node JS and Node-RED to the latest version,
a connection timeout error occurs when running the program.

[image]

Could it be that the postgres ([node-red-contrib-postgres-variable](https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-contrib-postgres-variable)) node is not compatible with the latest version?

Windows 10 Pro
Node.js version: v14.17.6
Node-RED version: v2.0.6
node-red-contrib-postgres-variable version: v0.1.4

Comment: Please do not post images of error text, they are very hard to read, impossible for people that use screen readers. Post the actual text and thne format it.

Comment: A connection timeout error most likely means that the problem is either that database is not running or that details you have entered for it are wrong and is unrelated to the upgrade.

Comment: The database is still running and the connection information I entered is correct, but I get a connection timeout error...

Comment: A Timeout error means that there has been no response by the remote system, so either the details being passed to the Socket library are wrong, the remote system it not running or there is a firewall between them dropping the packets

Comment: Thank you for your reply!
I think not, because before upgrade, node postgre still works fine with `Node.js v12.7.0` and `Node-RED v0.20.7` . I will continue to investigate

Comment: `0.20.7` to `2.0.6` is an absolutely massive jump in version numbers. But there is also an outstanding pr for NodeJS 14 support https://github.com/lotockii/node-red-contrib-postgres-variable/pull/5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, this is down to a [bug](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/pull/2171) in the underlying node-progress library with regard to NodeJS v14.

There is an [pull request](https://github.com/lotockii/node-red-contrib-postgres-variable/pull/5) for the node-red-contrib-postgress-variable node to fix this, but at this time it has not been merged.

Your options are

- Wait for the PR to be merged and then upgrade
- Modify the `package.json` locally and run `npm install` in the node's directory
- Downgrade NodeJS to v12

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use an alternate postgre contrib node. There are a few in the flows library: https://flows.nodered.org/search?term=Postgre&type=node

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).